# Buttons with Bootstrap ToolTip inside DataTable Cells [Not working]

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a little problem... . To make easy and extract problem of my main project, I have a simple table with few columns and some data, last column have two buttons with bootstrap tooltip, but this is not working. This is my code:

> I'm using DataTable plugin v1.10.16 and Boostrap v3.3.7.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>DataTable - Buttons with ToolTip</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>

 <section class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-sm-12">
    
    <table class="table">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>LastName</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Jhon</td>
       <td>Jhosson</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>
        <button id="ButtonA" class="btn btn-primary" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Action Name" style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">A</button>

        <button id="ButtonB" class="btn btn-danger" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Action Name" style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">B</button>
       </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Scalert</td>
       <td>Lopez</td>
       <td>33</td>
       <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Action Name" style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">A</button>

        <button id="ButtonB" class="btn btn-danger" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Action Name" style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">B</button>
       </td>
      </tr>

     </tbody>

    </table>

   </div>


  </div>


 </section>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 

  $(document).ready(function(){

   $("[data-toogle='tooltip']").tooltip();

   $(".table").DataTable({

    "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "LastName" },
                    { "data": "Age" },
                    { "data": "Button" }
                ]

   });

  });

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I found that **if eliminate property columns in main instance**, *it works without problem*. But, I can't delete it because I have other button that execute a function to table update and I need set it to make Binding/Match with JSON Object.

Somebody have a idea how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem using datatable jquery plugin. In the first page all buttons works perfectly but in other pages they don't work. If you  are using the plugin then my suggestion is either don't use the plugin or disable pagination.

Comment: If you could add some code to help nourish your answer, it would be great! :)

Comment: $('#example').dataTable( {
    "paging": false
} );

Comment: Thanks for reply @RobinKhan, I disabled the pagination, but the problem persist (although in my specific case, this solution don't is possible, because my main app have a few thousand records and I make query 500 in 500 results). On the other hand, disable jQuery "I think don't is viable" because DataTable plugin require jQuery to work.

Comment: sorry that couldn't help you bro but hope you will find the solution very soon